# How to differentiate active users from non active ones

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I built an app and I would like to differentiate the behaviours of my users regarding their activity levels. 
Objectives : make monthly users become daily users by understanding how daily users use the app vs monthly users and trying to narrow the gap between them.

I am well aware of the Daily / Weekly / Monthly active users Firebase offer but it is still a snapshot at a specific time.

Basically, if someone open a session at least one time during 20 days / month =>  highly active users, if someone opens it at between 7-20 times a month => medium active user, if someone opens it less than 7 times => low active users.

Do you have any clue on how to split these to then understand their behaviour?

Comment: You've tagged this with firebase-database and firebase-authentiation, but it sounds like you're asking about firebase-analytics.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the tags, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

because you are tagging your question firebase database that means you want to do it programmatically.
you can make a field in user node name it counter and every time the user login to the app you just increment the counter and make a query to bring the count that's it.

Comment: I delete the database tag and add the analytics, thanks for your comment.